# Which module should I import to use a PyHKEY?

Tags: python, pywin32

I'm attempting to win32api.RegLoadKey part of the pywin32 extension, however, I am assuming I need to create a PyHKEY first. But I don't know which module PyHKEY is in. The documentation is equally useless. http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/PyHKEY.html Note also that the documentation which is there does note that a PyHKEY is just a PyHANDLE, which is just an int, but using a int in the call causes Exception: `error: (6, 'RegLoadKey', 'The handle is invalid.')`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

A quick update:

```
import win32api

handle = int()

win32api.RegLoadKey(handle, "tempKey", "C:\\Users\\Default\\NTUSER.dat")
```

Comment: The reason you get that exception is that int() returns 0, so (in C terms) you're passing (HANDLE)0—which is, of course, an invalid handle, not the handle of a valid key. In other words, it's not the type that's wrong, it's the value.

Comment: Ok, I looked up the msdn article and figured out what was wrong, thanks! I was confusing win32api.RegLoadKey with win32api.RegLoadAppKey which takes a pointer to a handle and initializes it, hence my confusion about the handle.

Answer (score 0):

Python is dynamic; you don't "use" types unless you create your own object, otherwise you use objects given to you. [`win32api.RegOpenKeyEx()`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/win32api__RegOpenKeyEx_meth.html) will give you a key object you can use, or, as the documentation for `win32api.RegLoadKey()` states, you can use one of 4 predefined constants to load a hive root.

Comment: Python is dynamically typed, yes!